# how get the selected value of dropdown in same php without ajax

Tags: php

I have 3 dependent dropdown which coded in php and to move on second dropdown i have to select the first dropdown.on the value of that first drop down it shows the value of second dropdown from the database.to show the database data in dropdown i need the selected value of firstdrop down.and it will use that value for select query like

```
("select id,name,city_id from tab WHERE city_id="$selectedvaluofdropdown).
```

Now the problem is i have to do this without redirecting the php page.and without using **ajax** or **jquery**.is it posible...

Comment: Why you can't use jquery and ajax?

Comment: its NOT POSSIBLE without jquery/ajax

Comment: Maybe you can get all possible data and save them to javascript's array. then when finid this page, you can handle this data in client. but this would slow down the page loading and kind of not safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set all the available values of dropdowns ​​in the variable  javascript them into json using json_encode. Then if you change the values ​​of the dependent change dropdown using js

Comment: will you please help me how i can do this client side.

Answer (score 0):

Drop down selection happens on client side. PHPs job is over once the page is displayed. You have to use AJAX / JQuery to do something like this (without redirecting or reloading the page).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to call php scripts without reloading the php unless you use AJAX.

Comment: how i can use it with ajax will u please explain it with any example.ajax is new to me i do not know how i can use it.plese explain it with 3 dependent dropdown which shows data from database and whole code must be in same page is it posible.